# Sorting algorithm with grouping numbers by length

Tags: algorithm

I was thinking about sorting algorithm that starts with categorizing numbers by their length (i.e group with number 3 and 4, and another with 100 and 101) and then sorting them in their collective groups which i think would decrease sorting time (maybe even adding first number grouping to even further decrease the comparing time). Does that make sense? Do you have any recommendation how one would start that?

Comment: `dict[num.ToString().Length].Add(num)`

Comment: This works only with integer sorting

Comment: What if most of your numbers have 6 digits, because they are homogeneously distributed over the range [0, 999999]? In an average case 90% of your numbers would have 6 digits. So now you need an algorithm to sort those 90%... If you then split by first digit, what with the remaining digits? The more you split into buckets, the more buckets to sort. Any way, look into radix, count, bucket sort algorithms.

Comment: It seems, you are looking for **Radix sort** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, assume that you split the dataset in `k` subsets of equal size `n`. The sorting workload would become `k.n.log(n)` instead of `k.n.log(k.n) = k.n.log(n) + k.log(k).n`.

So from a theoretical standpoint, this makes no difference because both asymptotic complexities are `O(n.log(n))`. From a practical standpoint, you have to trade the gain on the number of key comparisons, to the loss due to extra element classification by length and pre/post-sort moves.

Only an actual implementation can tell you.

Comment: The `k.log(k).n` term is the cost of working out which of the k subsets each element belongs in; it takes `log k` comparisons to decide for one element. So there is no theoretical saving at all, not just no asymptotic saving.

Comment: @kaya3: no, the classification is based on the number of digits, not on comparisons. We have a linear-time overhead in any case, but we cannot reason without actual costs.

Comment: It's not; you said both asymptotic complexities are O(n log n) but that is not correct; both asymptotic complexities are O(kn log kn) = O(kn log n + kn log k). If the asymptotic complexity were O(n log n) then you could choose n = 1 with a large k and sort in constant time.

Comment: @kaya3: In my discussion k is a constant. Indeed, if n could be brought down to 1, technically the sort would be in constant time. But as k is constant, this cannot be.